# Reading ASP.NET ASPX Comments

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm taking over an old ASP.NET project that is being run inside our company.

Most of the stuff I am following, but I'm not sure if some of this code is commented out or if this is something to hide the code from the Browser.

Green is the color of comments, and a lot of this stuff is green.

Most of my work is typically on Windows Forms or the occasional T-SQL. I asked the guy here at work that does our website programming if this was a comment, and he wasn't sure. He said he'd never seen that type of coding before.

Does it run or is it a comment?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <%--<style type="text/css">
        td {color: Purple; border-color: purple;}
   </style>--%>
<%--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// This Script is used to maintain Grid Scroll on Partial Postback
var scrollTop;
//Register Begin Request and End Request 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
//Get The Div Scroll Position
Function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{
var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
scrollTop=m.scrollTop;
}
//Set The Div Scroll Position
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
m.scrollTop = scrollTop;
} 
</script>--%>
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

Since the code block will not show the comment colors, I will display a screenshot along with it.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything between <%-- and --%> is commented out and does not run, which appears to be most of this page.  So, yes, if it's green, it's commented out and will not run.